# How to manage multiple tables generated by scripts

Tags: mysql, symfony

I am using symfony2 and doctrine2

I am familliar with Entity and DB system already, but now, 
I would like to make tables like this.

`User` is correspond to `entity\User.php`, `Indice` is correspond to  `entity\indice.php` and `Market` is correspond to  `entity\market.php` .

However I would like to create Company** dynamically by script and manages.

Is it possible to do with my symfony2, doctrine and mysql??

```
User 
Indice
Market
Company1
Company2
Company3
Company4
.
.
.
```

Comment: why do you need dynamic Company tables? Why not single table with some identification attribute

Comment: If I combine Company** tables into one it will be 100million record.., So I would like to separate. (Please imagine like stock chart per minutes)

Comment: It is possible but doing with symfony and doctrine will be too complicated by generating dynamic entities , updating DB structure periodically (when new company introduced in system) clearing prod cache, bidirectional relationships will be associated with company**  etc